# Struts2 avoid duplicate form submission on page reload

Tags: java, struts2, struts-tags

I'm setting up a project with struts2 for study but I'm having problems with the token tag to validate a duplicate form request, I always get the error

"Could not find token name in parameters."

JSP:

```
<s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:token/>
    
    <s:textfield name="usuarioForm.userName" id="usuarioForm.userName" label="User ID" />
    <s:password name="usuarioForm.password" id="usuarioForm.password" label="Password" />
    <s:submit value="Login" />
</s:form>
```

I've tried everything I found on the internet, but nothing worked